# Insert whole table in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically I have a list of 92 Currencies (ID & Name) from Google:

https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/appendix/currencies

Can I insert all the data at once into Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: A useful trick is to load the data into a spreadsheet then use a string concatenate function to generate the SQL statement for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just download the .csv file and remove the first row which is column header and run
the following code. keep your .csv file in C drive.

```
create TABLE Currencies
(
CurrecyCode nchar(5),
CurrencyName nvarchar(30)
)

BULK
INSERT Currencies
FROM 'c:\currencies.csv'
WITH
(
CODEPAGE='RAW',
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Import/Export wizard from Management Studio to get data from csv. Just right click on your database, select Tasks->Import Data and follow wizard, it's quite simple.

Here is a link providing tutorial:
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/203/simple-way-to-import-data-into-sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using only a few rows, a couple of mins in the editor to generate a SQL state is all you need.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(ID,  Name)
VALUES
('AED', 'United Arab Emirates Dirham'),
('ARS', 'Argentine Peso'),
('AUD', 'Australian Dollar'),
('BGN', 'Bulgarian Lev'),
('BND', 'Brunei Dollar'),
('BOB', 'Bolivian Boliviano'),
('BRL', 'Brazilian Real'),
('CAD', 'Canadian Dollar'),
('CHF', 'Swiss Franc'),
('CLP', 'Chilean Peso'),
('CNY', 'Chinese Yuan Renminbi'),
('COP', 'Colombian Peso'),
('CZK', 'Czech Republic Koruna'),
('DKK', 'Danish Krone'),
('EGP', 'Egyptian Pound'),
('EUR', 'Euro'),
('FJD', 'Fijian Dollar'),
('GBP', 'British Pound Sterling'),
('HKD', 'Hong Kong Dollar'),
('HRK', 'Croatian Kuna'),
('HUF', 'Hungarian Forint'),
('IDR', 'Indonesian Rupiah'),
('ILS', 'Israeli New Sheqel'),
('INR', 'Indian Rupee'),
('JPY', 'Japanese Yen'),
('KES', 'Kenyan Shilling'),
('KRW', 'South Korean Won'),
('LTL', 'Lithuanian Litas'),
('MAD', 'Moroccan Dirham'),
('MXN', 'Mexican Peso'),
('MYR', 'Malaysian Ringgit'),
('NOK', 'Norwegian Krone'),
('NZD', 'New Zealand Dollar'),
('PEN', 'Peruvian Nuevo Sol'),
('PHP', 'Philippine Peso'),
('PKR', 'Pakistani Rupee'),
('PLN', 'Polish Zloty'),
('RON', 'Romanian Leu'),
('RSD', 'Serbian Dinar'),
('RUB', 'Russian Ruble'),
('SAR', 'Saudi Riyal'),
('SEK', 'Swedish Krona'),
('SGD', 'Singapore Dollar'),
('THB', 'Thai Baht'),
('TRY', 'Turkish Lira'),
('TWD', 'New Taiwan Dollar'),
('UAH', 'Ukrainian Hryvnia'),
('USD', 'US Dollar'),
('VEF', 'Venezuelan Bolí­var Fuerte'),
('VND', 'Vietnamese Dong'),
('ZAR', 'South African Rand')
```

If you're using copy and paste using the Alt + select ([columnar select](http://newoldthing.wordpress.com/2006/01/26/how-to-make-column-mode-selection-in-visual-studio/)) in the SSMS to select columns of text to add the quotes easily.

Edit: Thought I'd spend a minute doing it in notepad

Answer (score 0):

You can grab CSV and import it into SQL Server using bunch of methods.

1. [Using Bulk Insert](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/)
2. [Using BCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337544.aspx)
3. [Using SSIS](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/12/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-database-table-using-ssis/)